# MySQL query volume of price changes by product id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table.  Every time a customer updates their product it stores the price.  That way I can monitor price changes made, a history if you like.

Table structure is

```
ID (Primary Key)

Date (DateTime)

Price (Decimal)

Product_ID (INT) - Foreign Key
```

I want to find the total times a price has changed between two dates per product and then add up the total.

So for example I could say on the home page "We have changed the price of X products 10th December 2013 - 20th December 2013)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do with a simple group by query.

```
select count(*), product_id from table where date>='' and date<'' group by product_id
```

This will give you the product id and the number of changes during that time period.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(priceChanges) 
FROM (SELECT count(*) as priceChanges 
      FROM Table 
      WHERE DATE BETWEEN start AND end
      GROUP BY product_id
     )
UNION
SELECT count(*), product_id 
FROM Table 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN start AND end
GROUP BY product_id
```

First row would be the entire sum and the rest would be number of price changes per product_id.

I don't like result sets like this because it will require logic on the application end to parse the result set. However, if you don't want to split this up and issue 2 queries, you're going to need application logic regardless.

Another thing you could do is only issue the bottom select statement, and compute the sum of all the counts as you process that result set.

If the query is slow, you may want to consider creating an index on the date column.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total,
       product_id
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN 'fromDate' AND 'toDate'
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: I had this before and it returns too many results.  I know for a fact the results it returns there are too many price changes.

Comment: Can you post some data ? it will be more clear. And it will return many records because we are group by Product_id it gets repeated with the number of product_id.